# initialize select2 more than twice, but first select2 element got reset

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I try to use select2 to make my select input easier to find data.

Let's focus on `<select....` only with class item_box, and here's my javascript with first select2 init.

When the page is loaded, the first select2 `.item_box` is a success, but when I try (let's say click button #addnewitem to append cloned html to #items) to click button #addnewitem. The first select2 `.item_box` is reset/becomes a normal select form and the select2 change to a new select form `.item_box_2`.

Here's my js and html, how to fix it?

```js
var items_sample = null; //variable to save html that i want to clone

$(document).ready(function() {
  items_sample = $("#items_sample").html();
  $('.item_box').select2(); //first select2 when dom is loaded
});

$("#addnewitem").click(function() {
  $("#items").append("<tr>" + items_sample + "</tr>"); //append the cloned html
  var current_item = $("#items").children().last(); //get latest html dom
  current_item.find(".item_box").attr("class", "item_box_" + $("#items").children().length + " w-full rounded border-[1.5px] border-stroke bg-transparent py-3 px-5 font-medium outline-none transition focus:border-primary active:border-primary dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:focus:border-primary"); //rename the class to add _index, example item_box_2, item_box_3, item_box_n
  $(".item_box_" + $("#items").children().length).select2(); //select2 ini for the cloned html
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="addnewitem" id="addnewitem">
<table class="mt-2.5">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Item Qty</th>
      <th>Item Price</th>
      <th>Item Total</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="items">
    <tr id="items_sample">
      <td>
        <select name="items[]['inventory_id']" id="items[]['inventory_id']" class="item_box w-full rounded border-[1.5px] border-stroke bg-transparent py-3 px-5 font-medium outline-none transition focus:border-primary active:border-primary dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:focus:border-primary">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Item</option>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="3">Option 3</option>
          <!--                @foreach($inventories as $inventory)
                    <option value="{{ $inventory->id }}">{{ $inventory->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
    -->
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="items[]['qty']" id="items[]['qty']" class="w-full rounded border-[1.5px] border-stroke bg-transparent py-3 px-5 font-medium outline-none transition focus:border-primary active:border-primary dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:focus:border-primary">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="items[]['price']" id="items[]['price']" readonly class="w-full rounded border-[1.5px] border-stroke bg-transparent py-3 px-5 font-medium outline-none transition focus:border-primary active:border-primary dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:focus:border-primary">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="items[]['total']" id="items[]['total']" readonly class="w-full rounded border-[1.5px] border-stroke bg-transparent py-3 px-5 font-medium outline-none transition focus:border-primary active:border-primary dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:focus:border-primary">
      </td>
      <td>
        <center><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="removeItem(this)" class="hover:text-primary" title="Remove Item"><i
                            class="fi fi-rr-trash"></i></a></center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><b>Total</b></td>
      <td colspan="2"><b id="total">Rp 0,00</b></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: We miss the data that fills in the fields

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the select id is not unique. See it working by removing the id.

```js
var items_sample = null; //variable to save html that i want to clone

$(document).ready(function() {
  items_sample = $("#items_sample").html();
  $('.item_box').select2(); //first select2 when dom is loaded
});

$("#addnewitem").click(function() {
  $("#items").append("<tr>" + items_sample + "</tr>"); //append the cloned html
  var current_item = $("#items").children().last(); //get latest html dom
  current_item.find(".item_box").attr("class", "item_box_" + $("#items").children().length + " w-full rounded border-[1.5px] border-stroke bg-transparent py-3 px-5 font-medium outline-none transition focus:border-primary active:border-primary dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:focus:border-primary"); //rename the class to add _index, example item_box_2, item_box_3, item_box_n
  $(".item_box_" + $("#items").children().length).select2(); //select2 ini for the cloned html
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="addnewitem" id="addnewitem">
<table class="mt-2.5">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Item Qty</th>
      <th>Item Price</th>
      <th>Item Total</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="items">
    <tr id="items_sample">
      <td>
        <select name="items[]['inventory_id']" class="item_box w-full rounded border-[1.5px] border-stroke bg-transparent py-3 px-5 font-medium outline-none transition focus:border-primary active:border-primary dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:focus:border-primary">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Item</option>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="3">Option 3</option>
          <!--                @foreach($inventories as $inventory)
                    <option value="{{ $inventory->id }}">{{ $inventory->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
    -->
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="items[]['qty']" id="items[]['qty']" class="w-full rounded border-[1.5px] border-stroke bg-transparent py-3 px-5 font-medium outline-none transition focus:border-primary active:border-primary dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:focus:border-primary">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="items[]['price']" id="items[]['price']" readonly class="w-full rounded border-[1.5px] border-stroke bg-transparent py-3 px-5 font-medium outline-none transition focus:border-primary active:border-primary dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:focus:border-primary">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="items[]['total']" id="items[]['total']" readonly class="w-full rounded border-[1.5px] border-stroke bg-transparent py-3 px-5 font-medium outline-none transition focus:border-primary active:border-primary dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:focus:border-primary">
      </td>
      <td>
        <center><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="removeItem(this)" class="hover:text-primary" title="Remove Item"><i
                            class="fi fi-rr-trash"></i></a></center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><b>Total</b></td>
      <td colspan="2"><b id="total">Rp 0,00</b></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```